# Procrun with org.apache.commons.daemon.Daemon

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-daemon

I wrote a Daemon by using the apache commons sample code:

```
public class LockDaemon implements Daemon {

@Override
public void init(DaemonContext context) throws DaemonInitException, Exception {
    LogManager.getLogger().info("initialized with arguments {}", context.getArguments());
}

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    LogManager.getLogger().info("Start called");

}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    LogManager.getLogger().info("Stop called");
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

}
```

Unfortunately the example does not mention how to install this class with procrun. Procrun needs a static "Start Method", which I do not have when using the code above.

So which start (and stop) method needs to be set for procrun to make the code above work?

Answer (score 0):

This is question is further discussed in this thread: [Howto setup a Daemon implementation as windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556478/howto-setup-a-daemon-implementation-as-windows-service)